# Integral of an adapted process might be not adapted?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, measurable-functions

In Karatzas and Shreve book, Chapter 3, the authors discuss the theory of stochastic integration using a filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ that satisfies the usual hypotheses.

At page 133 point (c) a process $X$ *measurable and adapted* is considered. The authors says that, under these conditions, the integral process

$$F_t(\omega)=\int_0^{t\wedge T}X_s(\omega)ds$$

($T>0$ is fixed) could not be adapted. I am struggling to find an example of such a situation. I thought that measurability and adaptability were sufficient conditions, under the usual hypotheses for the filtration, to guarantee adaptability of the integral process.

Comment: Which edition of the book are you reading?  My copy says we can't _immediately_ guarantee conclude $F$ is adapted, but then gives a proof that it is.

Comment: Second edition. You are right, it says "we can't immediately guarantee". I stopped here trying to find out why.